# PYTHON - Change local variable in a function as needed; but leaving the default value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that takes a **string** (x) and and return a string that doesn't contain **certain punctuation** (not all punctuation are removed). I want the function to be customized for every situation. For example, sometimes I want to leave the exclamation mark **!!!** and not remove it.
Here is my code:

```
def remove_extra(x):
    '''Remove punctuation from a string as needed'''
    leave = ['‘', '—', '-', ' ', '’', '\n']
    new_x = []
    for i in x:
        if i.isalpha() or i in leave:
            new_x.append(i)
    new_x = ''.join(new_x)
    return new_x
```

I could easily create a new function and change the local variable leave; but that's extra work... I am thinking about decorators; but as beginner it seems to me it'll complicate the solution not simplify it.

Please give me your suggestions. I want the original function remove_extra() customizable.

Comment: Just add a second argument to your function.  What am I missing?

Comment: Add an optional parameter and extend the leave list with it?

Answer (score 4):

This will do the trick.

```py
def remove_extra(x, extra=None):
    '''Remove punctuation from a string as needed'''
    leave = ['‘', '—', '-', ' ', '’', '\n']
    if isinstance(extra, list):
        leave.extend(extra)
    new_x = []
    for i in x:
        if i.isalpha() or i in leave:
            new_x.append(i)
    new_x = ''.join(new_x)
    return new_x

foo = 'This is test sentence with!!!'

print(remove_extra(foo))
print(remove_extra(foo, ['!', ',']))
```

Output:

```
This is test sentence with
This is test sentence with!!!
```

---

If you want to use `*args` here is the possible solution

```py
def remove_extra(x, *args):
    '''Remove punctuations from string as needed'''
    leave = ['‘', '—', '-', ' ', '’', '\n']
    leave.extend(args)
    new_x = []
    for i in x:
        if i.isalpha() or i in leave:
            new_x.append(i)
    new_x = ''.join(new_x)
    return new_x

foo = 'This is test sentence with!!!'

print(remove_extra(foo))
print(remove_extra(foo, '!', ','))
```

Output:

```
This is test sentence with
This is test sentence with!!!
```

Comment: What about the old list? I think if you appended the old list (local variable named leave) this could work better. Sorry you already did.

Comment: There is a little problem. Try to repeat the call without passing extra.

Comment: But with the original string that is.

Comment: You should define the extra with `extra=None`. Then test and  externd the values..

Comment: @progmatico edited a bit, let me know if the issue still remains. Can't figure out what you are referring to.

Comment: If you define the optional parameter to hold a mutable, the mutable will be the same instance in every call. If you do not pass it in a later call the previous one is still used, leaving chars you did not want. Jusr add another call with `foo = 'This is test sentence with!!!'`and then  `print(remove_extra(foo)` to see.

Comment: The problem is the optional mutable is evaluated at definition time only. It will remain the same list instance forever.

Comment: It looks OK now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @wim and  @progmatico; putting optional argument solves the problem. I think it can be improved with decorators (containing properties)...

```
def remove_extra(x, *args):
    '''Remove punctuations from string as needed'''
    leave = ['‘', '—', '-', ' ', '’', '\n']
    leave.extend(args)
    new_x = []
    for i in x:
        if i.isalpha() or i in leave:
            new_x.append(i)
    new_x = ''.join(new_x)
    return new_x
```